# How configure two pages myproj/a and myproj/b in a Firebase project?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, web-applications

I have two webapps - "manager" and "viewer" - coded in separate VSCode projects. These are deployed to a common Firebase project where they share a common database. The "manager" webapp is used to maintain the database and the "viewer" provides public read-only access.

To create the "page" structure I have added a robocopy to React's build script for each VSCode project to produce a structured "mybuild" folder with the page subfolder within it. Firebase.json's "public": setting is then used to deploy from "mybuild".

Individually the two pages work fine, but each deployment overrides the functionality of the other. So, following the deployment of "manager", webapp/viewer returns a 404 (not found) error and vice versa.

To cut a long story short, the only way I've found around this is to manually copy the results of a deployment for one project into the "mybuild" folder of the other and then deploy from this. But this is no way to proceed.

I think I've taken a wrong turn somewhere here. Can anyone suggest the correct "firebase solution" for this requirement?  In the longer term I'd like the viewer webapp to be available at the root of some user-friendly "appurl" while the manager is accessed via "appurl/manager", but other arrangements would be acceptable. The main issue right now is finding a simple way of maintaining the arrangement.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to fix this fast, so here's my own answer to my question.

It seems that when you deploy a project, firebase replaces the current public folder for your URL with the content of whatever folder is specified in your firebase.json. So I decided that I had to accept that whenever either of my projects was deployed it must deploy from a "composite" folder that contains the build files for the other project as well as its own build.

That being the case, it seemed I was on the right lines with my "manual copy" approach and that what I now needed to do was simply to automate the arrangement.

Each of my projects now contains a script file with the following pattern:

```
npm run build
ROBOCOPY build ./composite/x /E
ROBOCOPY ../y/build ./composite/y /E
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

In each script, x is the owner project and y is the other. Additionally, firebase.json in each project is edited to deploy from composite.

When I run the script for a project it first builds a composite folder combining the latest build state for both that project and its partner, and then deploys the pair.

The final twist is to tell the react build process that the result is to be deployed from a relative folder and so that the build therefore also needs to use relative references. I do this by adding a

```
"homepage": "https://mywebapp/x",
```

to the package.json for each project. Here, x is the name of the project.

I'm not able to convince myself that there's not something wrong with my whole approach to this issue, but at least I have a fix for the immediate problem.